# Erlang finish or kill process

Tags: process, erlang, parallel-processing

I have erlang application. In this application i run process with `spawn(?MODULE, my_foo, [my_param1, my_param2, my_param3]).`

And my_foo:

```
my_foo(my_param1, my_param2, my_param3) ->
  ...
  some code here
  ...
  ok.
```

When i open etop i see that this my_foo/3 function status: `proc_lib:sync_wait/2`

Than i try to put exit(self(), normal) in the end of my function, but i see same behavior: `proc_lib:sync_wait/2` in etop.

How can i kill or exit process correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Note that `exit(Pid, Reason)` and `exit(Reason)` do **NOT** do the same thing if `Pid` is the process itself. `exit/1` tells the current process to exit - from the *inside* if you like - while `exit/2` sends an *exit signal* to the process, even if the process is itself. So when you do `exit(self(), normal)` you are actually sending the `normal` exit signal to yourself, which is ignored.

In this case putting the `exit` call at the end of the function should not make any difference as the process automatically dies (with reason `normal`) when the function with which it was started ends. It seems like the process is suspended somewhere before that.

`proc_lib:sync_wait/2` is called inside `proc_lib:start/start_link` and sits and waits for the spawned process to do `proc_lib:init_ack/1/2` to return the return value for start. It would appear that your process does not call `init_ack`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited information that you give in the question I would suspect that your process hasn't finished running yet.

Normally you don't need to add `exit/2` to your process.  It will exit automatically when the function has finished running.

You probably have a long running call in `some code here` that has not finished running.  I recommend that you add logging information and see where you are stuck.